# Provlem with integrating Sentry with Laravel app - User Feedback

Tags: php, laravel, sentry

I'm trying to integrate Sentry with my Laravel app. Basic error reporting is working but I'm stuck on User Feedback.

I followed the official [Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/php/integrations/laravel/)

For error 500 im getting default google chrome http request 500 error.

For errors 419 and others, laravel renders default error pages.

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're gonna need to post some code..

Comment: You'll want to look in your logs - either the webserver's, or `storage/logs` in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I checked in logs, that i didnt place

```
use Exception;
```

in Handler.php.

Thanks for help.